# Searching using LEFT JOIN combined with WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I need to join data from 2 different table this tables are also from different databases. I need to join them in 1 Table.

Here is the illustration:

TABLE1

```
----------
dr_no    prd_sys_code   ship_code

123         ABC1               01

321         ABC2               02

----------
```

TABLE 2

```
----------
prd_sys_code  ship_code   serialno

ABC1             01         A

ABC1             01         B

ABC1             01         C

ABC1             01         D

ABC1             01         E

ABC1             01         f
----------
```

TABLE 3

```
----------
dr_no      CSerialNo  status

123            A       P

123            B       P

123            C       P

----------
```

OUTPUT

```
----------
serialno  status

  A         P

  B         P

  C         P

  D

  E

  f

----------
```

Im thinking of using left join combined with where clause but I dont know the proper way to achieve this., I played around with the code but its error;

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT DB1.TABLE2.serialno, DB2.TABLE3.status FROM DB1.TABLE2 LEFT JOIN DB2.TABLE3 WHERE DB1.TABLE2.prd_sys_code='ABC1' AND DB1.TABLE2.client_code='01', WHERE DB2.TABLE3.dr_no = '123'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a `LEFT JOIN` you need to use `ON` syntax to define the link between the 2 tables. Also, you can't have 2 `WHERE`s in your query. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html.
Try something like this -

```
SELECT 
   inventory.prodserial.serialno, service2.installation2.status
FROM 
   inventory.prodserial
LEFT JOIN 
   service2.installation2
ON
   inventory.prodserial.serialno = service2.installation2.CSerialNo
WHERE 
   inventory.prodserial.prd_sys_code='$prd_sys_code' 
AND 
   inventory.prodserial.ship_code='$ship_to'
AND 
   service2.installation2.dr_no = '$dr_no'
```

note I had to change a couple of your column names in your `WHERE`/`AND` clause to match the column names in your posted tables. Also, make sure you are escaping your data to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: it worked I just removed this Line: "AND 
   service2.installation2.dr_no = '$dr_no' " Thank you :D